# What is the best javascript library to implement a browser tool for drawing diagrams

Tags: javascript

I have to implement a diagram tool in a web browser. To do that implementation which is the best JS library?

I found these three:

- kineticjs
- jointjs
- Raphaël

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each one for the implementation of a tool to draw diagrams?

Comment: We will need some more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically please list your requirements rather than asking for a comparison of different options.

Comment: See also [Stack Overflow: Graph visualization library in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [GoJS](http://www.gojs.net/latest/index.html) is a general purpose JavaScript diagramming library

There's loads of built-in interactivity that make it easy for users to create and modify their own diagrams. See a flowchart example [here,](http://www.gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html) or lots of other diagram types [here.](http://www.gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html)

- Built in, users can drag and drop nodes from palettes, draw new links, rearrange/resize nodes, reshape links.
- Templates for Nodes, Links, and Groups, can be arbitrarily complex and include [custom shapes/geometries](http://www.gojs.net/latest/intro/geometry.html)
- Support for user-created links with arbitrary [link validation](http://www.gojs.net/latest/intro/validation.html)
- With links, Orthogonal and Bezier link routing with "Avoids Nodes" and "Jump Over" options
- Data binding with JSON data
- Intuitive Drag-and-Drop & Copy-Paste functionality
- Unlimited extensible Undo and Redo
- Mouse and touch support with customizable tools
- Automatic layout of graphs
- Palettes and Overviews